# Count the number of three subsets that satisfy

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ element.How many way to choose three subsets $A, B, C$ of $S$ that satisfy $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: I feel this is a duplicate but I failed to find it. It may work as outlined in the answer here but I feel a more efficient approach is this: given that the sets are nested  knowing how many of the sets $A,B,C$  contain some $s \in S$ suffices to know in which sets $s$  can be found. Thus those triples of sets are in bijection with functions from $S$ to $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and those are easy to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the amount of subsets with $k$ elements from $S$. There are $\binom{n}{k}$ of those (by basic combinatorial theory). Now, look at the subsets of the set with $k$ elements again. The subsets can have $j \leq k$ elements, and for every $j$ there are $\binom{k}{j}$ elements. You can write a nested summation if you keep this idea in mind.

Does this help you enough to get an answer on your own?